# loops and nested lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops, combinations

I have two nested lists:  `files = list(l1, l2)` and `my_list = (l1=c(...),....l10 = c(...))`
When I run one for loop, I am able to get a second list, my_list_2 with the correct information.
For example:

```
##create an empty list
my_list_2 <-list()
for(i in 1:length(my_list)) {
  my_list_2[[i]] <- my_list[[i]] %>%
  map (function (x)  str_extract(filesI[[1]], x ))%>% 
    unlist(my_list[[i]]) %>% 
    discard(is.na)
}
my_list_2
```

When I try to perform a second for loop to perform this action to a number of files, I get the info that I want for both files but in one list `my_list_2`.

```
for (j in 1:length(filesI)) {
  for(i in 1:length(my_list)) {
    my_list_2[[i]] <- my_list[[i]] %>%
    map (function (x)  str_extract(filesI[[j]], x )) %>% 
      unlist(my_list[[i]]) %>% 
      discard(is.na)
  }
  my_list_2
}
```

I am not able to write the correct output and get a list per j in my filesI list. Any good idea, any suggestion how to do that??

Comment: You are rewriting the list `my_list_2` every time through the outer loop. Would nested lists do what you need or do you want just one output list?

Comment: Hi, and thank you for helping out. The ideal output would be a nested list containing a number of list from 1:j.

Comment: Sorry, if it was not clear. l = l1, l2,....lj

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following will do it. Untested, since there are no data.

```
my_list_2 <- vector("list", length = length(filesI)*length(my_list))
nm <- expand.grid(i = seq_along(my_list), j = seq_along(filesI))[2:1]
nm <- apply(nm, 1, paste, collapse = "_")
names(my_list_2) <- nm

for (j in seq_along(filesI)) {
  for(i in seq_along(my_list)) {
    this_name <- paste(j, i, sep = "_")
    my_list_2[[this_name]] <- my_list[[i]] %>%
      map (function (x)  str_extract(filesI[[j]], x )) %>% 
      unlist() %>% 
      discard(is.na)
  }
}
```

---

### Edit

To have nested lists as output, try instead

```
filesI_list <- vector("list", length = length(filesI))
names(filesI_list) <- sprintf("filesI_%02d", seq_along(filesI))

for (j in seq_along(filesI)) {
  filesI_list[[j]] <- vector("list", length = length(my_list))
  names(filesI_list[[j]]) <- sprintf("my_list_%02d", seq_along(my_list))
  for(i in seq_along(my_list)) {
    filesI_list[[j]][[i]] <- my_list[[i]] %>%
      map (function(x)  str_extract(filesI[[j]], x )) %>% 
      unlist() %>% 
      discard(is.na)
  }
}
```